# How can i do inheritance with three levels (father, child, grandchild)

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.x

I have the under

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Operation(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, a, use_sftp):
        print "OPERATION"

        self.a = a
        self.use_sftp = use_sftp
        self.y = 5

    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass


class OperationExecutor(object):
    def __init__(self, a, use_sftp):
        print "EXECUTOR"

        self.a = a
        self.use_sftp = use_sftp

    def batatas(self, operation):
        op = operation(self.a, self.use_sftp)
        return op.execute()


class FTP(Operation):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, a, use_sftp):
        print "FTP"

        self.op = super(FTP, self).__init__(a, use_sftp)
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.x = 10

    def execute(self):
        if self.use_sftp:
            return SFTP(self.a, self.use_sftp).execute()
        else:
            return LFTP(self.a, self.use_sftp).execute()


class SFTP(FTP):
    def execute(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c + self.x + self.y


class LFTP(FTP):
    def execute(self):
        return self.a * self.b * self.c * self.x * self.y


def main():
    executor = OperationExecutor(1, True)
    print executor.batatas(FTP)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i want to run in the following order:

EXECUTOR,
FTP,
OPERATION

or similar, but i have the following:

EXECUTOR,
FTP,
OPERATION,
FTP,
OPERATION

This is because "init" is called twice. **I don't want the "init" to be run more than once**

Operation (father) ---> FTP (child) ---> SFTP/LFTP (grandchild)

Comment: Just how do you envision running `__init__` only once, when you specifically create two objects of the class?  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? You should almost certainly tag it with the Python-2 tag, Python 2 is beyond it's end of life, and the assumption is that you will be using Python 3 unless otherwise stated, nowadays.

Comment: maybe you should use `FTP` only as `Factory` to create `SFTP` or `LFTP`. Wikipedia: [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)